# TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract English titles from a wiki titles dump that's in a text file using regex in Python 3. The wiki dump contains titles in other languages also and some symbols. Below is my code:

```
with open('/Users/some/directory/title.txt', 'rb')as f:
    text=f.read()
    letters_only = re.sub(b"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text)
    words = letters_only.lower().split() 
print(words)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

at the line: `letters_only = re.sub(b"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text)`

But, I am using `b''` to make output as byte type, below is a sample of the text file:

```
Destroy-Oh-Boy!!
!!Que_Corra_La_Voz!!
!!_(chess)
!!_(disambiguation)
!'O!Kung
!'O!Kung_language
!'O-!khung_language
!337$P34K
!=
!?
!?!
!?Revolution!?
!?_(chess)
!A_Luchar!
!Action_Pact!
!Action_pact!
!Adios_Amigos!
!Alabadle!
!Alarma!
!Alarma!_(album)
!Alarma!_(disambiguation)
!Alarma!_(magazine)
!Alarma!_Records
!Alarma!_magazine
!Alfaro_Vive,_Carajo!
!All-Time_Quarterback!
!All-Time_Quarterback!_(EP)
!All-Time_Quarterback!_(album)
!Alla_tu!
!Amigos!
!Amigos!_(Arrested_Development_episode)
!Arriba!_La_Pachanga
!Ask_a_Mexican!
!Atame!
!Ay,_Carmela!_(film)
!Ay,_caramba!
!BANG!
!Bang!
!Bang!_TV
!Basta_Ya!
!Bastardos!
!Bastardos!_(album)
!Bastardos_en_Vivo!
!Bienvenido,_Mr._Marshall!
!Ciauetistico!
!Ciautistico!
!DOCTYPE
!Dame!_!Dame!_!Dame!
!Decapitacion!
!Dos!
!Explora!_Science_Center_and_Children's_Museum
!F
!Forward,_Russia!
!Forward_Russia!
!Ga!ne_language
!Ga!nge_language
!Gã!ne
!Gã!ne_language
!Gã!nge_language
!HERO
!Happy_Birthday_Guadaloupe!
!Happy_Birthday_Guadalupe!
!Hello_Friends
```

I have searched online but could not succeed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text)` instead

Comment: @imant i tried this also but i am getting below error: **TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to choose between binary and text mode.

Either you open your file as `rb` and then you can use `re.sub(b"[^a-zA-Z]", b" ", text)`  (`text` is a `bytes` object)

Or you open your file as `r` and then you can use `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text)`    (`text` is a `str` object)

The second solution is more "classical".

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with the `repl` argument you supply, it isn't a `bytes` object:

```
letters_only = re.sub(b"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", b'Hello2World')
# TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

Instead, supply `repl` as a bytes instance `b" "`:

```
letters_only = re.sub(b"[^a-zA-Z]", b" ", b'Hello2World')
print(letters_only) 
b'Hello World'
```

---

Note: Don't prefix your literals with `b` and don't open the file with `rb` if you aren't looking for `byte` sequences.

Comment: very nice, I did not know it could be done on bytes. However I'm not sure it's the way to go here. Better go text-only and drop the bytes. Well, maybe it avoids encoding problems.

Comment: that works , now there is no error. But i am getting "b" prefix to every extracted word. Like this **[b'you', b'and', b'then', b'some']**but i think according to you it should not be there.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you were right ;-). Sherlock, just open the file without specifying `b` as @Jean suggests in his answer. `b` prefixed to the mode when opening files results in them being read as `bytes` objects, if that isn't what you need, drop it :-)

Comment: Let me say I'm pleased of the way the things turned out: Jim is the most knowledgeable of us all, he knew about the ability to use regexes for `bytes`, although us, mere mortals, just wanted to use a text file and knew zip about that! So everyone learned something and noone got bashed (I almost deleted my post at some point)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `byte` string for your regex match when the replacement string isn't.
Essentially, you can't mix different objects (`byte`s and `string`s) when doing most tasks. In your code above, you are using a binary search string and a binary text, but your replacement string is a regular `string`. All arguments need to be of the same type, so there are 2 possible solutions to this.

Taking the above into account, your code could look like this (this will return regular `string` strings, not `byte` objects):

```
with open('/Users/some/directory/title.txt', 'r')as f:
    text=f.read()
    letters_only = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text)
    words = letters_only.lower().split() 
print(words)
```

Note that the code does use a special type of string for the regex - a raw string, prefixed with `r`. This means that python won't interpret escape characters such as `\`, which is very useful for regexes. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for more details about raw strings.

Comment: actually you CAN do it, see Jim's answer. You should know it, I know it for at least ... 5 minutes :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hmmmmmmm... I do too now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `br'…'`, which is the byte analog to `r'…'`. The replacement must also be a byte string.

```
letters_only = re.sub(br'[^a-zA-Z]', b' ', text)
```